# 'Tk' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror, spyder

I am new to Python.  I downloaded Spyder 2.3.1 and am running Python 2.7 on my Mac.  I tried this sample program:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I run, I get the error message:

```
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

If I look in the file Tkinter.py, it has the following lines of code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Looks like an infinite loop, but what it is complaining about is "Tk" saying "name not defined".  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

p.s. I tried `python -m idlelib.idle` in a Terminal window and got the error `NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename `Tkinter.py` prevent the import of the standard library module `Tkinter`.

Rename the file with different name. Also you shouold remove `Tkinter.pyc` if there it is.

Comment: one more question.  I see files open in Spyder that are in the folder path /Users/Ameade/.spyder2/My_Amazing_Script.py - but I don't see a folder called ".spyder2" anywhere.  Can you tell me where this is?

Comment: @user3229570, In Unix sytem, the filename starts with a dot `.` is hidden. You can see the file with command likes `ls -a`. If you don't use command line, check your file browser's option to show hidden files/directories.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to navigate there using the Go menu.  I think I will just move these files to another folder.